# Use CSS to move charts close to each other

Tags: css, charts

I have two charts. One is bigger than the other. The bigger one consist of two labels called a and b. The small one consist of label c and d. Code for both charts are similar as the following.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Rra', 3880],
            ['b', 50],
        ],
        type : 'donut'

    },


});


var chart = c3.generat
       size: {
        height: 200,
        width: 450
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['c', 50],
            ['d', 50],
        ],

    },


});
```

I was wondering if it is possible to move the small chart between the empty space in the big chart.  So they end up looking like two layered charts. I did inspect element on the small chart and tried to use css to tweak the `transform="translate(225,83)"` to different values. However i noticed when the small chart got close to the bigger chart parts of it disappeared.

I am not expert in css or charting libraries and would love inputs on how to achieve this. Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hstmzatb/)

Comment: Can you render both of your charts into some DIVs with your custom classes then move those DIVs closer together?

Comment: @crazymatt i just posted my fiddle as well

Comment: It would help if you posted the rendered HTML in question and any relevant CSS. A fiddle would be even better

Comment: @zgood i just posted fiddle i am so sorry i was going to i totally forgot and now i did

Comment: @crazymatt if i assign same div id to both only one of them will get displayed

Comment: @Dinero No problem. This may be possible, but I would be worried about the keys of the charts.

Comment: @zgood by keys of the charts do you mean the legend ?i would not mind making one chart bigger and the other smaller to make a perfect fit.

Comment: @Dinero are you looking for something like this?  [Your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hstmzatb/1/)

Comment: @Dinero Sorry yes I mean the legends. Are you looking for something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hstmzatb/2/)?

Comment: Looks like @zgood may have your answer. I was thinking you wanted them side by side  :)

Comment: @zgood yes something like that exactly, so i think in this case you moved it around using css, is it possible to write css in such manner that chart1 is always drawn in center of chart no matter where chart1 is placed? Also if we make the other chart bigger the legend would fit for it right?

Comment: @crazymatt Something like what zgood just posted is what i am looking for

Comment: @Dinero Yes it is possible. That is the purpose of the wrapping `div` I called `chart_container` in the fiddle. `#chart1` is absolutely positioned with `left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);` from that wrapping div so it will always be in the center. So you can move you wrapping div around wherever you need to and `#chart1` would always be in the center. I have update the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hstmzatb/3/) to use a dynamic `top` value as well.

Comment: @zgood you should also post your answer i definitely think you deserve upvotes. I am just trying to get the 50% label to show, if you notice it is kind of cut off if we make the width bigger it might be visible right? however our chart might not be in center anymore. what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do agree with YourConscious's answer (using the d3 plugin to create what you want instead of using hacky CSS), here is the CSS method I have come up with:

```
.chart_container{
    position:relative;
}

#chart1{
    position:absolute !important;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You can see it in action in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hstmzatb/3/)

The magic is wrapping both charts in a container div, setting it to `position:relative;` so you can position your smaller chart off of it. Then give your smaller chart the above styles to always position it in the middle of the larger chart.

The `!important` is there because it seems the plugin is putting an inline style of `position:relative`

Comment: One thing to note is that for the the `top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);` to position it exactly in the center the second chart would probably have to be half the width and height of the larger one. If the larger one is 400 by 600 the smaller one would need to be 200 by 300 to be in the center

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it.. with `position:absolute;` and nesting. But I wouldn't really recommend it and will likely not be that stable *(z-index issues, mobile, updating it later on, etc).*

I think that library has direct documentation and capabilities to create multiple layers / rings. Why not just do the right way?

**Exaggerated example (5 layers / rings)**

```
var dataset = {
  apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  oranges: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  lemons: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  pears: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  pineapples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    cwidth = 25;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(10+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1))(d); });
```

[**J Fiddler**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/154/).

Also, this might be a good [resource](http://christopheviau.com/d3list/):

Comment: Yes, I would agree with this. If you can do it without hacky CSS then do it that way... it'd be more stable in the long run. I do not know much about d3

Comment: I have experience with High Charts, but they look really similar. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki